# Including bootstrap with Gulp

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, sass, gulp, bower

I am working on a project that uses gulp to build the javascript and css for the project and requires bootstrap. While the import partially works, I am running in to a lot of font-related errors on page load. This is what I tried:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    pump([
        gulp.src(
            [
                'path/to/jquery.js',
                'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
```

....
....

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(
        [
            'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
```

Again, while the default bootstrap styles and javascript seems to be included in the project, I am getting errors similar to the ones below. Any ideas how to resolve this?

```
TS parsing error: invalid version tag
(index):1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://my.domain.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2?448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb
```

Comment: Not particularly familiar with gulp, but is there a way for you to match only sass files? At first glance it looks like you're trying to compile css as sass, and I'm guessing the sass compiler doesn't know how to handle fonts.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. gulp-sass can handle scss as well as css files. Also, I tried using bootstrap-sass and including a bootstrap.scss and it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your actual setup your bootstrap glyphicons also need to be added to your /dist/fonts to get called at runtime. As they are not included in the bootstrap-sass build cycle when using gulp-sass.

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {


"gulp": "^3.9.1",

"gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",

"gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",

"gulp-imagemin": "^3.0.3",

"gulp-newer": "^1.2.0",

"gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",

"gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",

"gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",

"gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0"

},
```

**Gulpfile**

```
// ////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// CONFIG
// 
// jsConcatFiles => list of javascript files (in order) to concatenate
// // //////////////////////////////////////////////

var config = {
    jsConcatFiles: [
        './src/scripts/js/jquery.js',
        './src/scripts/js/bootstrap.js',    
    ], 

};


var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    newer = require('gulp-newer'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),


// ////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Scripts Tasks
// ///////////////////////////////////////////////

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.jsConcatFiles)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/scripts/js'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public_html/scripts/js/'))
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});


// ////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Styles Tasks
// ///////////////////////////////////////////////

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('src/scripts/scss/styles.scss')

        .pipe(rename('all-styles.css'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public_html/scripts/css'))
        .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});





// ////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Watch Tasks
// // /////////////////////////////////////////////

gulp.task ('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('src/scripts/scss/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('src/scripts/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});


gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'styles', 'watch']);
```

Also include the glyphicons in your /dist/fonts.

glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot

glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg

glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf

glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff

glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2

Comment: Thanks James. I’m aware of the points mentioned. Can you provide a working example / gulpfile linking to bower ?

Comment: if i get time ill try and sort a working example - in the mean time, do you have " /public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2? 448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb " or "public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2" (without the hash) - as your errors might be your hashing setup..

Comment: Have been trying to recreate your error, how are you generating the hash / version number string for the  fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2?448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb) file.